# Share LAN Internet FROM Windows 10 INTO Lollipop by USB or Bluetooth connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, android, bluetooth

I have a Desktop Windows 10 PC with LAN and WAN connections (WAN: Wide Area Network, Internet). but no WiFi in it, but it has an USB Bluetooth 2.1 adapter plugged in. I have also an Android Galaxy S4 Lollipop without data plan. Mi Wifi router is broken until I buy a new one or have enough time to fix it.

Instead of share internet from my android to the PC via USB or Bluetooth tethering, I want to share it into the phone from the PC.

Windows 10 don't show any Tethering option in the Network Config.

Can I get internet on my phone from Windows 10 via USB or Bluetooth?